# How can I call Native class from my Portable class and get result from Native class to Portable class in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I call Native class from my Portable class and get result from Native class to Portable class in Xamarin.Forms
Please help me with that

Comment: A Bit confused what you want, you want to call a function of a class in android in your portable project ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Dependency services for that. Here is the link [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/)